# Как разбить длительный скрипт на части?

Tags: javascript

Привет.

Чтобы была плавная анимация должна поддерживаться большая (60) фпс. Для этого, как говорят, надо, чтобы скрипт был разбит на кусочки по  10 миллисекунд. Не понимаю, что подразумевается под словами "разбить скрипт на части"? Скрипт - это последовательность инструкций, а инструкции ОТДЕЛЯЮТСЯ точкой с запятой друг от друга. То есть, скрипт - последовательность ИЗНАЧАЛЬНО ОТДЕЛЕННЫХ друг от друга частей-инструкций. Браузер выполнил одну инструкцию и СРАЗУ ЖЕ принимается за следующую. Раз пишут про 10 миллисекунд, то получается, что можно как-то "упаковать" инструкции, чтобы инструкции "пачками" выполнять. Как это сделать? Между этими пачками зазоры временные есть? как понять, что одна "пачка" (набор) инструкций отделена от другой "пачки" инстуркций? У меня есть только одна мысль, как отделить два набора инструкций - это запихать один набор в одну функцию, а другой - в вторую, причем вторую функцию вызвать сетТаймаутом. Больше идей нет. Когда таймеры начинают использоваться в скрипте, а скрипт сложный, можно очень легко запутаться в скрипте.

Comment: мой вопрос из сферы оптимизации производительности браузера, а не из сферы оптимизации критического пути рендеринга

Comment: `Для этого, как говорят, надо, чтобы скрипт был разбит на кусочки по 10 миллисекунд` - можно поинтересоваться кто и где говорит?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/

Comment: `В реальности же браузеру нужно выполнить и еще кое-какие действия, потому вся ваша работа должна занимать не более 10 мс.` ........... ни слова про `скрипт был разбит на кусочки по 10 миллисекунд` ....уж извините про мысли вслух

Comment: работа это и есть скрипт

Comment: вам говорят про то, что не написано нигде, что скрипт должен быть разбит на куски по 10мс, как это интерпретировали вы. А не про сопоставление слова работа и слова скрипт

Comment: я ничего не понял из того, что вы написали. как вы лично поняли то, что написано по ссылке, которую я скинул?

Comment: Дружеский совет - используйте **полужирный**  или _курсив_ для выделения слов, КАПС ОБЫЧНО РАСЦЕНИВАЕТСЯ КАК КРИК.

Comment: никогда бы не подумал, что капслок расценивается, как крик). первый раз такое читаю

Answer (score 2):

Выполнение скрипта как правило происходит синхронно. Во время синхронного выполнения все действия в браузере полностью блокируются до окончания выполнения скрипта. Вы не сможете при таком подходе и выполнять долгий скрипт и что-то еще при этом обновлять. Вам придется ждать, пока весь скрипт полностью не выполнится.

FPS - Frame Per Second - это сколько раз за секунду перерисовывался экран, т.е. что-то на нем обновлялось при необходимости. Поэтому фактически Вам надо выполнить набор инструкций, сделать паузу дав браузеру время проанализировать/применить инструкции и потом снова запустить следующую порцию синхронных инструкций. Для этого используются не синхронные, а асинхронные функции. Типичный пример, это [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) и [SetInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval). А так же разнообразные события браузера.

**UPD**

Для примера примерного списка асинхронных событий, можно почитать данную статью: [ruseller: Основы построения асинхронных приложений](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?id=1655&rub=28)

Можно так же рассмотреть типичный случай анимации или как вариант проще счетчика, что бы понять всю суть происходящих событий. По сути, счетчик, это как раз типичный случай рендеринга значений.

Синхронный вариант работать не будет.

***Внимание! Скрипт ниже после нажатия на кнопку скорее всего намертво повесит страницу или даже весь браузер.***

```js
document.getElementById("startCounter").onclick = function(e){
  var counter = document.getElementById("counter");
  for(var i=0; i<10000000000000; i++) {
    counter.innerText = i;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="startCounter" value="Сломать" />
<div id="counter">0<div>
```

А вот использование асинхронных событий будет работать исправно и нормально обновлять страницу в браузере, поскольку они не блокируют выполнение потока до момента своего запуска.

```js
 document.getElementById("startCounter").onclick = function(e){
      var counter = document.getElementById("counter");
      setInterval(function(){
        counter.innerText = parseInt(counter.innerText) + 1;
      },4);
    }
```

```html
<input type="button" id="startCounter" value="Все нормально" />
<div id="counter">0<div>
```

Comment: насколько я знаю,  setTimeout и SetInterval - это таймеры. а асинхронным и синхроным бывают не функции, а скрипты. <script async></script> - асинхронный скрипт. <script></script> - обычный блокирующий скрипт.<script defer></script> - отложенный скрипт

Comment: насчет паузы - передышка браузеру для применения инструкций не нужна. передышка нужна для того, чтобы, если я нажму, например, кнопку, то не пришлось бы ждать окончания выполнения длинного скрипта, а функция-обработчик могла быть отловлена в этом зазоре между скриптами

Comment: @Dimon, обновил ответ. Вы приводите пример указания способов **загрузки скриптов браузером**, а не их синхронности или асинхронности. По этой теме очень много написано. Для примера, посмотрите на счетчик с применением асинхронного пути и синхронного. Первый способ вешает страницу намертво, второй работает исправно. Тоже самое с другими инструкциями, если Вам нужна плавность, то надо давать браузеру паузу. К примеру, если бы делаете анимацию через JS или у Вас есть долго выполняющийся скрипт и надо выводить его результат по мере выполнения.